# Check value if exist only in first table and not in second table

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have two SQL tables "user" and "entries".

I want to check with only one query if the user exists in first Table "user" or not and if the user has maked an entry in table "Entries" or not.

I want to make something like rating system. Where user should exist in table "user" and has no Entries in Table "entries". Because every user can make only one entry.

Is it possible to do it with only one query, how can i do it?

I know only how can i do it with two queries

```
SELECT COUNT(*) amount FROM user
```

AND

```
SELECT COUNT(*) quantity FROM entries WHERE user_id = $userID
```

Comment: I don't see the relationship between the two queries.  Can you provide some sample data here?

Comment: See `LEFT JOIN ... IS NULL`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the "NOT EXISTS" operator:

```
SELECT id FROM user
WHERE id = $userID
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM entries where user_id = $userID);
```

It will return a row only if the user exists in the table "user" and has no entries in the table "entries".

Comment: Thank you! I have a little bit improve it. EXISTS is slow. IN should be used

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/exists-to-in-optimization/

SELECT id FROM user
WHERE id = $userID
AND id NOT IN (SELECT * FROM entries where user_id = $userID);